# Javascript: the object field is undefined if passed as 'this' as function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have something like page controller `Page`,  and I would like to use model `Tim` and do the callback to the another method from `Page` controller.

Could you please explain what is going on here?

The code looks like below:

```
//the model:
var Tim = function(){};
Tim.prototype.setDuration = function (duration) {
    this._duration = duration;
};
Tim.prototype.count = function(doSomething) {
    doSomething(this)
}

//the Page controller:
var Page = function(tim){
    this.tim = tim; // initialisation of this.tim
};
Page.prototype.init = function () {
    this.tim.count(this.pollStatus);
};
Page.prototype.pollStatus = function(tim) {
    this.tim = tim; // I still have to assign this.tim for the second time
    $.ajax({
          url: 'http://end/point',
          type: "GET",
          success: function (data) {
               this.tim.setDuration(data.duration); 
          }.bind(this)
     });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
     var tim = new Tim();
     var page = new Page(tim);
     page.init();
 })
```

I have to assign this.tim two times, because it is `undefined` if not.

Comment: Where is `tim` declared?

Comment: what is tim and what is the result of "prints function"?

Comment: You should share `tim`

Comment: `tim` is passed as parameter to `pollStatus`.

Comment: @nibsa Show us an example of `tim` being created as a function and failing to be used as a function.

Comment: Stop a debugger at that point and see what it is doing.

Comment: Can you post the code where you call `pollStatus()`?

Comment: Ok, I added some background code, I hope it is clearer now :)

Comment: When I run all of that in fiddle there's no error associated with Tim. Is all of this code in one file on your end as well? Your comments look like these bits of code are in separate files in which case make sure you import or include Tim.

Comment: Well, the `Tim` model resists in another file, but that file is loaded earlier. I'm still getting this error, even if I place `Tim` just above the `Page`. I'm so confused about this error

Comment: What browser and version of jQuery are you using?

I ran your code on Chrome and Edge with no errors.

Comment: I'm using jQuery v1.11.0 & Chrome Version 51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `doSomething(this)` in

```
Tim.prototype.count = function(doSomething) {
    doSomething(this)
}
```

the context for `doSomething` is global, and `this` inside it is `window`.

You know what `bind` is, use it:

```
Page.prototype.init = function () {
  this.tim.count(this.pollStatus.bind(this));
};

Page.prototype.pollStatus = function(tim) {
  //this.tim = tim; now the code works without this assignment
  ...
```